# Is there a way to sign on as a guest in the Xbox dashboard?

Tags: xbox-360

I have noticed that quite a few of the games I play allow me to have a second player split-screen online with me by signing in as a guest. I always do it by starting up the game and then through that sign my friend in as a guest, but isn't there a way to sign in as a guest on a second controller without launching a game first?

I'm asking this because some games allow you to splitscreen with a guest account but they don't offer you the opportunity to sign in as a guest so you have to launch a second game that does first.

Comment: I've never encountered a game where I couldn't sign in as a "guest" to play in splitscreen.  What game is this in reference to?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no way to sign in as a guest from the Xbox 360 Dashboard because signing in as a guest doesn't have any meaning until you're trying to play online.  The purpose of signing in as a guest is to utilize the online features of a game without having to pay for Live Gold yourself.  Instead, you piggyback on another gamertag's subscription.

Microsoft [describes](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/907336) it this way:

> Gold Membership account holders can create temporary guest accounts for the purpose of game play.

The major features of the Xbox Live dashboard (themes, achievement progress, avatars, etc) are available to any profile, regardless of Live status, so signing in as a guest doesn't really apply.

If you can't seem to sign in as a guest, it may be because you're signed into a profile on the second (or third/fourth) controller already.  Sign out of the non-Xbox Live Gold profile and try again.

Comment: I wish to use the guest account function not just for online play but for local play as well, because if I want to play "Castle Crashers" with 3 friends, I have to create 3 profiles for my friends to use instead of just having them sign in as guests which is really a nuisance because I don't want temporary profiles lying around so I always delete them

Comment: There's no support for this as far as I can tell.  I'd suggest creating a "Player X" profile for each person you want to play offline with you, if this happens often.  If the extra profiles irritate you, you'll have to choose between creating them/deleting them every time and dealing with them when your friends don't want to play.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can all you need to do is sign into a Xbox live gold account then play a game like minecraft then it will come up with the second player needs to sign in press guest then you will spawn and number 1 will be player and number 2 will be player(1)